# gnuplot: annotate plot with X and Y lines

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to plot the inverse of y=xe^x, with dashed lines leading to the point (-exp(-1), -1)

```
set parametric
set style arrow 1 head filled size char 1.5,20,50 

set arrow 1 from -4.1,0 to 4.1,0 heads  
set arrow 2 from 0,-4.1 to 0,4.1 heads

set trange[-4:4]
set xrange[-4:4]
set yrange[-4:4]

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

unset border

set xtics axis format " "
set ytics axis format " "

plot [-4:0.999] log(1-t)/t, t

plot [-4:4] t*exp(t), t lt rgb "black" title '',  -exp(-1),t lt rgb "black", t, -1 lt rgb "black"
```

I would like to restrict the vertical line to running from y=-1 to y=0, and the horizontal line from x=-exp(-1) to x=0. How can this be done?

Also, is there an easier way to set the line colour for all plots, rather than specifying it for each one?

[image: example]

Comment: you mean you want to scale your x and y axis between `-exp(-1):0` and `-1:0` respectively, or is something else?

Comment: @ZahaibAkhtar I updated my post with a link to an image of my plot because I wasn't sure if I understood your question. I would like the horizontal dashed line to be restricted from y= -e^(-1) to y=0 and the  vertical dashed line to be restricted from x=0 to x=-1.

Answer (score 0):

I see, if I'm understanding it correctly you basically need to annotate your graph with the dashed lines, so why don't you use arrows for the same too.

For example:

```
# I'm using pngcairo dashed terminal
set terminal pngcairo dashed
set output 'graph.png'

set parametric
set style arrow 1 head filled size char 1.5,20,50 

set arrow 1 from -4.1,0 to 4.1,0 heads  
set arrow 2 from 0,-4.1 to 0,4.1 heads

#set trange[-4:4]
set xrange[-4:4]
set yrange[-4:4]

set xlabel "x"
set ylabel "y"

unset border

set xtics axis format " "
set ytics axis format " "

#plot [-4:0.999] log(1-t)/t, t

set arrow from -exp(-1),-1 to -exp(-1),0 nohead lt 3
set arrow from -exp(-1),-1 to 0,-1 nohead lt 3

plot [-4:4] t*exp(t),t  lt rgb "black" title ''
```

[image]

As far as your questions about line colours is concerned, it is also dependent on the type of terminal that you are using. For instance, with the pngcairo terminal, Gnuplot will itself assign different `linestyles` to plots. If you want specific colours, then offcourse you have to state them. Take a look at [this link](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/dashcolor.html). You'll find lots of info with a simple search on Gnuplot's `linestyles/linecolour/linetypes` etc.